# Как убрать кнопки зума WebView, но чтобы зум жестами продолжал работать?

Tags: android, android-webview

Нужно убрать кнопки `zoom` в `webView` Android, при этом, чтобы зум работал. Сделал так:

```
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
if (API >= 11) {
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
}
```

В `Android < 4.0` всё идеально. В 2.x кнопки зума есть. Если же `settings.setBuiltInZoomControls`
объявить `false`, тогда и кнопки уйдут, и `zoom` отключится. Варианты?

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос... Нужно чть бы зум при помощи остальных средств работал, а кнопки отключить?

Comment: Именно. то есть если пальцами сделать "щипок, ущипнуть", то сработал зум. но при этом это убожество (кривые кнопки) не показывались. Бьюсь над проблемой...

Comment: без костылей на ранних версиях андроида никак. попробуйте это решение https://stackoverflow.com/a/14751673/7540461

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант. Должен работать нормально. Просто задаем размер кнопок в 0 и пользователь их не увидит.

```
private WebView myWebView;
private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS =
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, Gravity.BOTTOM);


FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
    getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final View zoom = myWebView.getZoomControls();
    mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: костыль какой-то :) надо глянуть как это сделано в либе FinestWebView, например